# Modal: load content only on click

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3, twig

Using Symfony2, TWIG and Bootstrap, I would like to to display modal windows ([as described here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)).

**But** I want to load the content of these modal only if the user click on the button to display it, not at the main page's loading.

Context: I have a list of elements on my main page, and I would like to give the possibility to the user to have more information about some particular elements (one at a time). So the user clicks on the element, the modal shows up and details appear. As there are quite a lot of elements and the detailled info are quite heavy to load, I want to load only the necessary ones, on demand.

I know and already use (for other things) TWIG's `{% include ... %}`,`{% embed ... %}` and `{% render ... %}`, I know how to display a TB Modal but I didn't find the way to do what I want :(

---

**[EDIT] SOLUTION**

For later reference. @Syjin's answer put me on the track but some additional details might be useful :-D

In the main Twig page, the one with the list:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="{{ path('MyBundle_MyEntity_seeModal', {'entity_id': entity.id}) }}" data-target="#myModal">Click me</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
</div>
```

Create a new Twig template `seeModal.html.twig` with the content of the modal, as described in the doc:

```
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Create the related route and Controller's action.

Comment: No, I believe this actually has very little to do with either `Symfony` or `Twig`. I would turn my attention to some `JS` libraries like `AngularJS` or `Knockout.JS`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the answer is right there in the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

You can either use the `remote` option of the modal and specify a path that should be loaded. Or if you are using the data-api you can set the `href` and the content will be loaded (one time) dynamically.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal">Click me</a>
```

Instead of the `remote.html` you would specify a route to your rendered modal content.

Comment: Easier and simpler than @bartek's solution, and works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the best way to accomplish that is to create new `action`, which returns your heavy data as JSON.

```
/**
 * @Route("custom/route/{params}", name="your_route", options={"expose": true})
 */
public function getSomething($params)
{
    // your custom logic here...
    return new JsonResponse($data);
}
```

You will also need some `jQuery` and get contents using `AJAX`. To generate routes using jQuery I suggest [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)

Finally, when you get your JSON data, just inject it into your `modal-body`

Comment: Yes, this is favorable way of doing it. However, beware that there is some weird bug in `Bootstrap` what does not allow modal to refresh it's content. It seems to me that initial (static) content gets saved into some structure and is never refreshed...

Comment: @jperovic I always clear my modal container and then fill it with data. Actually I've never met this bootstrap bug you mentioned...

Comment: Oh, it might be some isolated bug, so I'm not surprised :)

Answer (score 1):

The `remote` option is removed since bootstrap v4.0.

If you use this version here are solutions:
[Bootstrap 4 with remote Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34763090/bootstrap-4-with-remote-modal)