# Bootstrap 4 load modal-Content from other page

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I would like to load the content of a modal from another page.
Here is my code:

```
     <!--End-Banner-->
  <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        <a href="imprint.html" role="button" data-target="#theModal"  data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-outline-success">Imprint</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Privacy Policy</button>
        </div>
  </footer>

<!--jquery-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--Scripts-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/imprint.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <!--Modal-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="theModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Like you see I would like to load the content of the imprint.html inside my modal-content. 
I tried the solution from an other question - [link to solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958219/getting-bootstraps-modal-content-from-another-page)
But it did not work for me.

Following my imprint.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis praesentium ipsam quidem sapiente nostrum? Ipsa saepe aperiam nulla cum repellat iure, porro dolor, adipisci totam quisquam, vel. Perferendis, nihil, sed!
  </p>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is happing now?
The Modal starts, but does not load, if I look in the console the modal-content stays empty.

Can you help me out?
Thank you very much.

Comment: In Bootstrap 4, you must handle the `show.bs.modal` event, to load the content using jQuery load as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48934494/171456).

Comment: oh it is a duplicate. I am sorry, I will have a look. Thanks

Comment: Though this might technically be a duplicate, it is not adequately answered. Further, unless I'm missing it, there is not reference to Bootstrap 4 documentation (which I doubt exists).  For the record, after a day of fighting code based on the previous "answers"... I did get it to work with Bootstrap 4.3.1