# jQuery Modal - Redirect from one Modal to another modal on Ajax success

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I checked this sources:
[Redirect from one Modal to another modal on Ajax success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48949733/redirect-from-one-modal-to-another-modal-on-ajax-success)

And I liked this sample:
https://www.codeply.com/go/HTDu4jkqSA

But I wanted to implement this solution, in this plugin.
https://jquerymodal.com/
https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal/blob/master/README.md

Is possible?

Comment: there is no "redirect" just use the modal api to close the current and open the other one on ajax-success ...

Comment: Sorry, but I need to pass the fields that the person filled in the first modal:
?name=xxxx&email=yyyy

Comment: you could check with js if the queryparameters are set, and if so open the according modal