# how to open a modal popup on anchor tag / link click in c# to open another .aspx page inside the popup

Tags: javascript, c#, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, popup

I want to open a .aspx page inside a bootstrap modal popup on the click of a link click or anchor tag click. the page should be the one given in href or any other option

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stackoverflow you might want to read up on: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide some sample code and explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 with remote Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34763090/bootstrap-4-with-remote-modal)