# How to Load Content from Another Page in Bootstrap 5 Modal? with Laravel 10

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap-5, laravel-10

My code view in // `index.blade.php`

```
<a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal_frame" href="{{route('caborCreate')}}">link</a>
```

My Modal code view in create page // `create.blade.php` //

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_frame" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <!-- Completes the modal component here -->
</div>
```

My code javascript in // `main.js`

```
$('#modal_frame').modal('show').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      $(this).find('.modal-body').load(event.relatedTarget.href);
    });
```

My routes // `web.php`

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->prefix('cabor')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/',[CaborController::class, 'index'])->name('cabor');
    Route::get('/create',[CaborController::class, 'create'])->name('caborCreate');
});
```

And I tried every answer source below:
[Bootstrap 4 with remote Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34763090/bootstrap-4-with-remote-modal)

I hope I get help quickly. answers are highly appreciated. Thank You.

My Error code get :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'backdrop')
    at Ue._initializeBackDrop (modal.js:158:39)
    at new Ue (modal.js:69:27)
    at Ue.getOrCreateInstance (base-component.js:65:41)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (modal.js:363:22)
    at HTMLDocument.s (event-handler.js:118:19)
_initializeBackDrop @ modal.js:158
Ue @ modal.js:69
getOrCreateInstance @ base-component.js:65
(anonymous) @ modal.js:363
s @ event-handler.js:118
```

Answer (score 1):

update the code in your main.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#modal_frame').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var modal = $(this);

        // Load content from the specified URL
        modal.find('.modal-body').load(button.attr('href'));
    });
});
```

The modal in your create.blade.php file seems to be incomplete. Make sure you complete it with the necessary structure.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_frame" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal Title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- Content will be loaded here -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

don't forget to include jQuery and bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I really appreciate it. It's just that I've tried like the answer you gave. but the problem is still the same. the problem in here, Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'backdrop'). thanks again for the answer

Comment: no issues, this error might be due to bootstrap version and how it is integrated with jQuery.